# Encrypt pdf by the server to prevent printing and copying

Tags: file-encryption

We are building a portal where users can upload few materials. we have been successful in using the command lines of linux to convert doc,ppts to pdf directly through the server but we are not able to encrypt those files from printing, editing and copying. 
Please provide us with some solution so that we can do it through our server directly.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to find a particularly effective method of preventing this. If the user was motivated enough they could take a photo of the document and print out the photos. I think physical security would be the only reasonable solution (ie. user can only access the documents in a controlled physical environment where they cannot access a camera, etc.).

Comment: You can consider flattening the pdf to prevent easy editting and copying. I don't believe you can ever fully prevent printing, editing or copying.

Answer (score 3):

Preventing of printing, editing and copying are just flags inside the PDF file which the reader might ignore. Probably most readers in Linux will ignore these flags by default, but readers like Adobe Acrobat Reader will enforce these restriction.

Encryption on the other side has nothing to do with these flags, it's for encrypting the content so that it is only accessible by someone who knows the password. It might be combined with these flags but it does not need to be.

To set these flags at the command line have a look at pdftk option allow.